# Matrices and Combinatorics are a bad combination.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let $\scr A$ be the set of all $n\times n$ symmetric matrices all of whose entries are either $0$ or $1$ and such that if $n$ is even, $n^2/2$ of these entries are $1$ and $n^2/2$ of them are $0$, and if $n$ is odd then $(n^2+1)/2$ of these are $1$ and $(n^2-1)/2$ are $0$.

I need to find:

- The number of matrices in $\scr A$.
- The number of matrices with non-zero determinant in $\scr A$. (and that also counts up indirectly the matrices with zero determinant.)

I have solved this problem for $n=3$ by explicitly writing the $12$ matrices with $6$ and $6$ matrices with zero and non-zero determinant.

Is there a general way to do this?

Comment: " If n is even, $n^2 / 2$ of these entries are ..." Is this a condition for a matrix to be in $A$ or is it a consequence? For example does the identity matrix belong to $A$ ? Thank You.

Comment: condition to be in $\scr A$

Comment: Then please edit the question so that the condition is more clear!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't even see how this is a problem, maybe someone who actually has a problem with that can only edit?

Comment: It is a problem, because the definition of the set $\mathcal A$ you gave is not tthe one you meant. You are th one interested in getting an answer, so it is **you** you should strive to be as clear as possible. **Remember that it is *you* who is asking for help here**...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ok I'll try, but..........

Comment: Your edit did not make things better, really.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I told you I'm not a native english speaker, even now I don't see a difference between the three versions.

Comment: Well, trust me. There is a difference. Before, you defined a set —the set of symmetric matrices of zeroes and ones— and then made a claim about its elements (which was false). As it stands now, the definition of the set includes two conditions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ok thanks anyways for the edit. :D

Answer (score 2):

I would go with an even matrix since this case is a little easier.

When we choose $i$ **$1's$** along the diagonal where $i$ is even(including 0). We would be left with $\left(\dfrac{n^2}{2}-i\right)$ **$1's$** for non-diagonal elements. However, there are also $(n-i)$ **$0's$** along the diagonal so there are total $\left(\dfrac{n^2}{2}-(n-i)\right)$ **$0's$** left to be distributed in the non-diagonal elements.

We know that any matrix is symmetric, hence, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$. Each element $a_{ij}$ is already fixed by the element $a_{ji}$. That means we can consider a pair $(a_{ij},a_{ji})$ which is always either filled by the pair $(1,1)$ or $(0,0)$. Number of these pairs to be filled is $\dfrac{\left(n^2-n\right)}{2}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Number of pairs of $(1,1)$ is $\left(\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{i}{2}\right)$ and number of pairs of $(0,0)$ is $\left(\dfrac{n^2}{4}-\dfrac{(n-i)}{2}\right)$, which are to be distributed among $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ possible pairs.

Finally, ways of choosing $i$ $1's$ are $^nC_{i}$

Hence required combinations can be,

$$\sum_{i=even} {^n}C_i \times \dfrac{\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n^2}{4}-\left(\frac{n-i}{2}\right)\right)!\times \left(\frac{n^2}{4}-\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

A matrix in $\mathcal A$ is determined by the $n$ entries in the diagonal and the $n(n-1)/2$ entries in its upper triangular part. Suppose now for example $n$ is even

If $i$ is the number of $1$s in the diagonal —which can be anything even from $0$ to $n$—  then the number of ones in the upper part is $n^2/2-i$. There are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways of putting the ones in the diagonal and $\binom{n(n-1)/1}{n^2/2-i}$ was of putting the ones in the upper part. It follows that the number of matrices in $\mathcal A$ is $$\sum_{\substack{i=0\\\text{$i$ even}}}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n(n-1)/2}{n^2/2-i}.$$ The odd case is entirely similar.

Comment: does it include "symmetric matrices"?

Comment: The number of 1 in diagonal cannot be anything, you gotta keep the matrix symmetric take the that means you require pairs of 1 and 0 in non - diagonal elements and distribute those pairs , essentially keep on subtracting 2 1's from diagonal and redistributing will do it.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand what I wrote?

Comment: The number of 1's in diagonal can not be anything from 0 to n ... Take two 1 in diagonal for a case of 3x3 , ah it's for even, haven't check that case tho.

Comment: There need to be an even number of 1's in the diagonal in the even case, and an odd number in the odd case.

Comment: Well @SamClearman , already stated what i wanted to. :)

Comment: $n=2$ and $i=0$